# Numerical integration, prove that weight are equal

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

If we have interpolation type formula $\int\limits_a^b p(x)f(x)dx = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n A_if(x_i) + R_n(f)$ and its points $x_i$ are symmetrical to the integration segment midpoint $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$, and p(x) is a paired function around c, then symmetrical points have the same weight. $x_i-c = c-x_j => A_i = A_j$.

$A_i = \int\limits_a^bp(x) l_{ni}(x) dx = \sum\limits_{j=0}^n A_jl_{ni}(x_j)$ Where $l_{ni}(x)$ is Lagrange polynomial.

Either this is very easy or very hard, I dont get it. To me it kinda seems obvious, that because $\int\limits_a^bp(x) l_{ni}(x) dx = \sum\limits_{j=0}^n A_jl_{ni}(x_j)$ then $p(x_j)=A_j$ and since p(x) is  paired around c then $A_j = A_i$.

Am i missing something?

Comment: "fonction paire" is french, you mean an even function $p$. Is there some assumption on maximal order or minimal number of sampling points?

Comment: @LutzL Yes an even function. As much as i understand it it basically is like this. We have a n sampling points. We use Lagrange interpolation on them to approximate the function between a and b. Now we integrate this approximation between the points a and b. Assumptions about p(x) are that p(x) >= 0 and integral p(x) from a to b is > 0. And the sampling points are symmetrical around c.

Comment: The idea is that reflection of $f$ at $x=c$ does not change the integral and thus should not change the integration formula. Maximum error order enforces uniqueness of coefficients and thus coefficient symmetry.

Comment: ummm.... while $x_i$ are symmetric around c, but this does not mean that $f(x_i) = f(x_j)$ only $p(x)$ is even function. And what do you mean under maximum error order? I cant seem to find what it is.

Comment: @LutzL i dont fully understnd what you are syaing.

Comment: The integrals of $f(x)$ and $f(2c-x)=f(a+b-x)$ over $[a,b]$ are always the same. In your computation, you should find that the Lagrange interpolation polynomial of symmetric points $l_{ni}(x)=l_{nj}(2c-x)$.